# How to use a dynamic collection name with JSP and Jquery

Tags: jquery, jsp

I have a model where I have added a group of arrays as attributes. in my JSP file I have a drop down menu with the names of those lists as the options. What I would like to do is when I select an option in the dropdown with the names, I would like to populate a second dropdown with that corresponding list that I have added. For example if I have selected List1 in the first dropdown I'd like to populate the second with the contents of List1 that I added to the model. From what I understand I need to use JQuery to do this.

Here is what I have in my JSP file:

```
<select id = "drop1" onchange="myJQuery.addDrop2Options">
    <option>List1</option>
    <option>List2</option>
    <option>List3</option>
</select>

<select id = "drop2">
    <c:forEach var = "name" items="${drop1.val()}">
        <option>${name}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Here is myJQuery

```
var myJQuery = {
    addDrop2Options : function (){
        $("#drop2").empty();
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what I need to change/add to make this work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create 3 hidden selects for 3 lists you have, and just pull the correct options from them to `drop2` select on change on `drop1` select. Something like below

In your JSP.

```
<select id="drop1">
    <option value="">-Select-</option>
    <option value="List1">List1</option>
    <option value="List2">List2</option>
    <option value="List3">List3</option>
</select>

<select id="drop2"></select>

<!--Wrapper hidden div to hold 3 select dropdowns for three lists-->
<div id="hiddenSelects" style="display:none">
    <!--populate this dropdown with List1 -->
   <select id="List1">
        <c:forEach var = "name" items="${list1}">
          <option>${name}</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
    <!--populate this dropdown with List2 -->
    <select id="List2">
        <c:forEach var = "name" items="${list2}">
          <option>${name}</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
     <!--populate this dropdown with List3 -->
    <select id="List3">
        <c:forEach var = "name" items="${list3}">
          <option>${name}</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
</div>
```

And the below is the jquery code.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#drop1").change(function (e) {
        var currentSelect = $(this).val();
        $("#drop2").empty();
        if ($("#" + currentSelect).length > 0) 
            $("#drop2").append($("#" + currentSelect).find('option').clone());
    });
   });
```

here is the **[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0xc6taap/2/)**